# запрос sql таблицы

Tags: sql

Есть связанные таблицы `заказы` и `рейсы`. Хочу подсчитать стоимость заказа, исходя из стоимости всех рейсов по этому заказу. Как это сделать?

```
CREATE TABLE `zakazy` (
      `zakazy_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    , `summ` FLOAT
);

CREATE TABLE `vzakaze` (
      `vzakaze_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    , `zakazy_id` INT
);

CREATE TABLE `vreise` (
      `vreise_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    , `vzakaze_id` INT
);

CREATE TABLE `reis` (
      `reis_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    , `vreise` INT
    , `stoimost` FLOAT
);
```

Comment: добавьте определение таблиц

Comment: Какой вопрос такой и ответ. Сделайте запрос, который считает стоимость всех рейсов, а затем посчитайте стоимость заказа...

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что вы собираетесь менять `zakazy.sum` каждый раз когда меняете таблицу `reis`. Это, в принципе, возможно сделать, с помощью триггеров, но это очень плохая идея. Если вам нужна такая информация, лучше сделать вьюху.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что бы выбрать информацию из двух таблиц, их сначала надо объединить в одну, делается это с помощь предложения `JOIN` в секции `FROM` запроса. (Не обязательно что бы таблицы были связаны через `FOREIGN KEY`).

Допустим у нас есть таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE INVOICE (
     Invoice_ID int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,Invoice_Description nvarchar(256)
    );
CREATE TABLE RUN (
     Run_ID int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,Run_Descrition nvarchar(256)
    ,Run_Price decimal(18,2)
    ,Invoice_ID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES INVOICE(Invoice_ID)
    );
```

Тогда ваш запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
SELECT i.Invoice_ID,  SUM(r.Run_Price) as price
FROM RUN as r inner join INVOICE as i ON r.Invoice_ID = i.Invoice_ID
WHERE i.Invoice_ID = 3 -- замените 3 на ваш номер заказа
GROUP BY i.Invoice_ID
```

**UPD**

Менять каждый раз таблицу `zakazy` каждый раз когда меняете таблицу `reis` это очень плохая идея хотя, в принципе, это возможно сделать, с помощью триггеров. Если вам нужна такая информация, лучше сделать вьюху. Я бы рекомендовал выкинуть из таблицы `zkazy` (дайте им нормальные английские имена, кстати) поле `summ` и сделать такой вью:

```
CREATE VIEW vZakazy 
AS
SELECT z.zakazy_id, SUM(r.stoimost) as stoimost
FROM reis as r 
    inner join vreise as v ON r.vreise = v.vreise_id
    inner join vzakaze as vz ON v.vzakaze_id = vz.vzakaze_id
    inner join zakazy as z ON vz.zakazy_id = z.zakazy_id
GROUP BY z.zakazy_id
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Дополнение к посту Mirdin:

Или возможно использовать оконные функции, если СУБД это позволяет, тогда можно избавиться и от WHERE:

Тогда ваш запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
SELECT DISTICT i.Invoice_ID,  SUM(r.Run_Price) OVER (PARTITION BY i.Invoice_ID) as price
FROM RUN as r inner join INVOICE as i ON r.Invoice_ID = i.Invoice_ID
GROUP BY i.Invoice_ID
```

Если же нужно среднее значение, то не SUM, а AVG соответственно.